# How do I batch these data into an Oracle database in mule?

Tags: mule

[image]

I want to pass the data to the service exposed by mule through post, and then insert the data into the database. If there is any solution that can be implemented, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not very much clear about the question (From where to pass the data). But you can try below steps assuming you have exposed web service in mule.

1. As this is post method, you will get the incoming request to web service as a payload.
2. Create database connection using Database connector.
3. Create dynamic insert SQL query and provide the values to the query from 
   request payload.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Database connector you should be able to do this. You need to have JDBC connector jar files and database which connects throught JDBC.

Please see below link for detail explanation of how to implement DB connector

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/database-connector